# how to load large data quickly from database in bootstrap datatable

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I want ask something about bootstrap datatables, I have a more than 3000 data in my database mysql. The datatables is running well, but the problem is when the time to load all data from db. I saw it in chrome developer tools, the time to load all the data 16 second. how I can get some trick or suggestion to fix it for little quickly to load the all data..??

this is my code in html

```
<div class="table table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive table-bordered table-hover" id="karyawan">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Action</th>
          <th width="5px">No</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">id</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">KD Klas</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Nip Lama</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">KD Tarif</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">KD Unit</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">No KTP</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">NIP Terbaru</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Nama Pegawai</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Alamat</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Tanggal Lahir</th> 
          <th style="text-align:center;">Tempat Lahir</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Agama</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Kelamin</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Status Nikah</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Departemen</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Jabatan</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Nama Unit</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Bagian</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Jenis Gaji</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Tahun Masuk</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Tahun Keluar</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Status</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Rekening</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Upah Bulan</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Upah Hari</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Lembur Per Jam</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Kode Kelompok</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Tunjangan</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">JHT</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">BPJS</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Shift</th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Tunshift</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <?php
            include_once("../../../../koneksi/conn.php");
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM pegawai order by idpeg DESC";
           $query = $koneksi->query($sql);
           $no=1;
          while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
              echo"<tr>";
              echo"<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='btnPopupEditKar' data-toggle='modal' data - target='#modalupdatekar' onClick='clickShowKar(this)' title='edit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></button>&nbsp<button   type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='delete' title='delete' onClick='confirmDeleteKar(this)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></td>";
              echo"<td>$no</td>";
              echo"<td id='IDPEG'>$row[0]</td>";
              echo"<td id='KDKLASS'>$row[1]</td>";
              echo"<td id='NIPLAMA'>$row[2]</td>";
              echo"<td id='KDTAR'>$row[3]</td>";
              echo"<td id='KODEUNIT'>$row[30]</td>";
              echo"<td id='KTP'>$row[4]</td>";
              echo"<td id='NIP'>$row[5]</td>";
              echo"<td id='NAMA'>$row[6]</td>";
              echo"<td id='ALAMAT'>$row[7]</td>";
              echo"<td id='LAHIR'>$row[8]</td>";
              echo"<td id='TEMPAT'>$row[9]</td>";
              echo"<td id='AGAMA'>$row[10]</td>";
              echo"<td id='KELAMIN'>$row[11]</td>";
              echo"<td id='NIKAH'>$row[12]</td>";
              echo"<td id='DEP'>$row[13]</td>";
              echo"<td id='JAB'>$row[15]</td>";
              echo"<td id='BAG'>$row[14]</td>";
              echo"<td id='NAMAUNIT'>$row[31]</td>";
              echo"<td id='JENGAJI'>$row[16]</td>";
              echo"<td id='TASUK'>$row[17]</td>";
              echo"<td id='TALUAR'>$row[18]</td>";
              echo"<td id='STATUS'>$row[19]</td>";
              echo"<td id='NOREK'>$row[20]</td>";
              echo"<td id='UBUL'>$row[21]</td>";
              echo"<td id='UHAR'>$row[22]</td>";
              echo"<td id='LEMJAM'>$row[23]</td>";
              echo"<td id='KODEKEL'>$row[24]</td>";
              echo"<td id='TUNJANGAN'>$row[25]</td>";
              echo"<td id='JHT'>$row[26]</td>";
              echo"<td id='BPJS'>$row[27]</td>";
              echo"<td id='SHIFT'>$row[28]</td>";
              echo"<td id='TUNSHIFT'>$row[29]</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
              $no++;
              }
           ?>
         </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and this in my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#karyawan").dataTable({
      "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, -1], [5, 10,"All"]],
      "iDisplayLength": 5
    });
});
```

thank you,
best regards

Comment: do you use pagination?

Comment: @LecheDeCrema: yes, the pagination from datatables is working fine. but i must waiting for 16 second to see the first data in page one.

Comment: how many data in one page ?

Comment: @LecheDeCrema: i set just 5 data in default. like example in my js code

Comment: Use [`serverSide`](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: Hai @philantrovert, sorry for my late respon. Do you have a some example or little explain to me about the serverside processing.?? This method can be solved my problem about the timing to load all data..?? Thank you

Comment: yess it's solved. thanks mr @philantrover.